# In migrating my website to display: flex tinyMCE editors not using full width of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tinymce

I am migrating my website from one which restricts itself to features supported by IE7 to one which demands a minimum of IE11.  In particular I am switching from using the original flow style to using display: flex which is supported since IE10 and of course on all modern browsers.  In most cases the behaviour remains consistent and I can get rid of the ugly hacks required to get the old style to work.  But for some reason when I change a row containing a tinyMCE editor to display: flex, the editor shrinks horizontally.

I am only changing the CSS.  The HTML remains:

```
<div class="row">
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="[enter message]"
            rows='5' cols='100'></textarea>
</div>
```

The old CSS definition of div.row was:

```
div.row {   white-space:        nowrap;
            clear:              both; 
            float:              left;
            width:              100%;
        }
```

The new CSS definition of div.row is:

```
div.row {   white-space:        nowrap;
            width:              100%;
            display:            flex;
        }
```

I have not changed tinyMCEparms:

```
 var tinyMCEparms = {
    selector            : 'textarea',
    plugins             : 'link lists image',
    menubar             : false,
    language            : 'en',
    skin                : 'oxide-dark',
    toolbar             : "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | " 
                           + "bullist numlist | link image",
    height              : "170px",
    content_css         : "/styles.css"
  };
```

The containing div has the same width as its container, 1520 in this case. If I do not activate tinyMCE on the textarea the width of the textarea is 1048.  The div with class="tox tox-tinymce" and everything inside it only has a width of 446! With the old CSS the width of the tinyMCE editor is 1048.  The documentation says the default width of the editor should be the width of the element it is replacing.  Why?

Over a year has gone by and I still cannot find an answer to this issue.  I have upgraded to TinyMCE6 and still the editor fails to size itself to the dimensions of the `<textarea>`.  To demonstrate that I have a feature on my pages that permits me to disable tinyMCE so I can see the underlying page:

[image: TinyMCE deactivated]

Note that to view this I have activated the browser feature to show the dimensions of the containing Flex box.  However when I activate tinyMCE on this page I see:

[image: TinyMCE Activated]

The problem is apparently that the browser believes there are FOUR items within the `<div class="row">` so the one "visible" tag only uses 1/4th of the available space. I only entered one, the `<textarea>`.  TinyMCE set that to display:none so it does not appear, but that leaves only one displayed tag within the '', the one with class="tox tox-tinymce".  Why is it displayed using only 1/4th of the width of the containing `<div>`.

Comment: I would have a look through the browser inspector to make sure nothing else is putting a constraint on it. If you have a psuedo element (like before/after) flexbox can get a bit messed up. Else, have you tried setting it so that it has a flex-grow property to force it to use all available space?

Comment: Thank you.  I collected all of the information in the description from the inspector.  I see no reason to change the HTML which was working.  Why is tinyMCE violating the documentation by not making the editor the same width as the textarea it overlays?

Comment: Over a year has gone by.  I have now updated to TinyMCE6 and still I cannot control the width of my editor boxes.